Is Heaven real?
You stand before an omniscient being. It is either God, who always tells the truth, or the Devil, who always lies. You don't know which. Your task is to figure out whether Heaven is real. You may ask the being one yes-or-no question in English. (Coercive logic is not permitted.)
Jeff is also here. He knows all the rules in the preceding paragraph and will hear the question and answer. You hate Jeff and do not want him to know whether Heaven is real.
What do you ask?

What exactly is coercive logic?

@VictorStafusa An example would be "Is is true either that heaven is real, or that you will answer no to this question?" God would be unable to answer if heaven isn't real, and the devil would be unable to answer if it is.

Wouldn't the existence of God and/or the Devil imply that heaven is real? So you already know the answer and sadly so does Jeff.

@Parrotmaster I used to play a game called Afterlife where you had to build an afterlife for humankind. In that game you could decide that the afterlife has no Heaven or no Hell (actually the Devil even reminds you that making a Heaven is not necessary at all). So in this situation, if it happens that you are talking to the Devil then you cannot imply that Heaven exists.

@Parrotmaster https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma Christianity or nothing supernatural are not the only options, there are infinite possibilities

@JollyJoker I feel like the usage of "God", "Devil" and "Heaven" implied we were talking specifically about Christianity. Especially the task "Figure out if Heaven is real" from a single question requires that we already know what "Heaven" is with some detail. If it can be any religion then that task is impossible.

@Elerium115 The fact that the Devil tells you Heaven isn't required should ring some alarm bells no? I feel like he might be biased.

What does Jeff have to do in there? And then, how can you ask a question that will reveal whether Heaven is real or not with him present and not wanting him to know the answer??? This doesn't make any sense.

The question has 3 flaws:

Jeff has nothing to do in there.
But even so, how can you ask a question that will reveal whether Heaven is real or not with Jeff present and not wanting him to know the answer?
You know that both beings are supposed to know that Heaven is real. (Otherwise, the question has no stable (constant) data based on which to evaluate any answers.)
What is the purpose then of the question if you already know that Heaven is real?

So, it would make more sense if you want to know whether the being you have in front of you is God or the Devil.

@Apostolos I guess every question you can't answer is likewise "flawed"?

@no comment.

The question that you would ask, if there was no Jeff out there is:

 If I were to ask the opposite omniscient being about if Heaven is real, what would he say?

God would answer:

 Whatever the Devil would say, which is a lie.

The Devil would answer:

 The opposite of what God would answer, hence, a lie.

So:

 The correct answer is the opposite of the given answer.

This works so far without Jeff and is the classic solution of the Jeff-less problem. To work around Jeff, there is a boolean operator that is handy in cryptography to add confusion:

 XOR

Mix the question with something that only you and an omniscient being know:

 Does my gmail password has an odd number of lowercase letters?

So what you should ask is:

 If I were to ask the opposite omniscient being about if Heaven is real XOR my gmail password has an odd number of lowercase letters, what would he say?

Hence, the given answer:

 Is the correct answer if your password has an odd number of lowercase letters and the opposite of the the correct answer if your password has an even number of lowercase letters.


...and then, ideally, change the "something that only you and an omniscient being know" afterwards so that Jeff can't go try to work out what it was.

My answer was similar but I tried to avoid the use of the XOR:  rot13(Bs gur fgngrzragf "Lbh ner Tbq", "Urnira vf erny", "V'z jrnevat juvgr haqrecnagf", ner gurve na rira ahzore bs gehr fgngrzragf?)

That's still essentially an XOR.

To expand on Lucenaposition's comment: rot13(N KBE O vf vqragvpny gb, "Qbrf [N,O] pbagnva na bqq ahzore bs gehr fgngrzragf?").

Yes, sorry, I meant to say I tried to avoid the word "xor" as it is maybe somewhat debatable if it is an English word,  but yeah it is equivalent.

@TylerSeacrest It is an English abbreviation for "exclusive or" and any omniscient being would understand it very clearly.

I first observed this in the '80s, watching Labrynth. But I wonder if this "what would they say" kind of tactic be considered a type of coercive logic? Particularly from the devil's point of view, as he is coerced into revealing exactly what he would be trying to hide.

You

 hold firmly in your mind either the question "If I asked you whether heaven is real, would you say yes?" or the question "If I asked you whether heaven is real, would you say no?", choosing between them as randomly as you are able

and then

 ask: "What is the answer to the question I was thinking about immediately before asking you this question?".

Then

 if your question was the "would you say yes?" question, then -- supposing for the moment that heaven is real -- God would say yes if asked whether heaven is real and will truthfully say so, whereas the Devil would say no if asked whether heaven is real and will falsely say he'd say yes; if heaven is not real then God would say no and hence will say no, whereas the Devil would say yes and hence will say no.

But

 Jeff, who unlike God and the Devil does not know what you have been thinking, will have no way to learn anything from the answer since he has no idea what question it is answering.


Just barely beat me to it!

Sorry! (Second time in a few days...)

I feel this is a loophole in the question. You might as well write it on a piece of paper since "Jeff" only hears what's going on, or use sign language.

I don't think I agree. The point is to make what's happening depend on something Jeff doesn't know but you and these omniscient beings do, or equivalently on something Jeff doesn't know but you do. You only need one bit of this "shared secret" to make the thing work, but the most obvious ways to get it all give you a lot more, so I thought it made things clearer and simpler to push the whole question into the "shared secret".

(The first thing I thought of did only use one bit of shared secret; I made the deliberate decision to do it this way instead because I thought it was neater.)

You can ask:

Are you glad that the place I am thinking of exists?

If Heaven does exist, God will answer:

  God is glad that heaven exists = YES

If Heaven does exist, the devil will answer:

  Devil is not glad that heaven exists, but lies = YES

If Heaven does NOT exist, God will answer:

  God cannot be glad that heaven exists, because it does not = NO

If Heaven does NOT exist, the devil will answer:

  Devil is glad that heaven does not exist, but lies = NO

Meanwhile:

 Jeff does not know of where you are thinking.


Ask the being:

 Is the boolean operation true: “Is heaven real” XOR “You are God” XOR “Is my middle name James”?

This makes use of a logical operation that helps us negate the truth of a statement. Some examples:

 The operation is called "XOR". We can use it as follows: 
A XOR True = NOT A 
A XOR False = A 

Let's start with a simple question we can build upon:

 Is the statement true: “Is heaven real”?  
 Let A be the answer to this question. God will answer A, truthfully. The Devil will lie and answer NOT A. Since we don't know the identity of the being, whether we hear a "yes" or "no" doesn't tell us anything about Heaven.

So let's simplify the lying problem:

 If God says "yes" but the Devil says "no", we don't know which is lying. This means their answer should be conditioned on their own identity. Let's add XOR "You are God" to our question.  
 Our boolean operation is now “Is heaven real” XOR "You are God". 
  - God will answer A XOR True = NOT A
  - The Devil will answer (NOT A) XOR False = NOT A
 The answer is unanimous. If either being says "yes", Heaven is not real. If either says "no", Heaven is real.

Unfortunately, Jeff has all the information we have, and learns whether Heaven is real. Let's take care of that:

 We add a personal question into the mix. For example: "My middle name is James". Our true middle name is only known to us and the omniscient being. So if we add XOR "My middle name is James" to our equation, there are 2 possibilities: 
  - Our middle name IS James, which means we negate the entire equation. 
  - Our middle name ISN'T James, which means we interpret the answer as before. 
 We know our middle name, so we know if we need to flip the being's answer. Jeff doesn't know, so the answer is useless to him.

